# Advanced SAT Practice

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

I'm helping some friends prepare for the SAT and I'm reviewing some SAT algebra practice. Can someone double check if my answer for these two questions are correct?

If x-8 $\sqrt{x}$ +16=0, which of the following a possible value for x? 
A) -16
B) -8
C) 0
D) 8
E) 16

For this problem I simply chose to substitute 16 for x because it is the only easy square root that can be taken. Once I simplified I got 0=0. So I chose choice E.

If g = 4$f$, 2$f$=3e, and 2e=4d, what is the value of d$^2$/g? I'm very confused how to approach this question because of the function f notation... Do I want to solve for d and then solve for g and substitute?

A) 6/1
B) 4/1
C) 1/2
D) 1/6
E) 1/8

Comment: We aren't here to double check your answers.  Besides, there is https://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: @SimpleArt Simply trying to understand concepts and how could I post a question like that to Wolfram? I genuinely just want to learn and understand.. is that so horrible?

Comment: Oh, no, of course not.  But TBH, on the last question you posted, it seemed like you *already* understood everything and that you were merely asking us to check your answers.  (and for the first problem, your method is sound, since obviously $0$ is a rational number, the left side must also be rational)

Comment: @SimpleArt Sorry I just don't want to be teaching people the wrong thing tomorrow and I didn't know what other source to turn to since this practice did not provide an answer key. I honestly have no idea how to approach the forth question though

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+x,+x+-+8*sqrt(x)%2B+16+%3D+0

Comment: All the letters here are variables, not functions. Just substitute in what you know and the variables will cancel, leaving a fraction

Comment: Hm, sorry, please use the full link above, not just the portion that is in blue.

Comment: wait so should I solve for d and g and then substitute? I feel like I am going in circles with that approach though...?

Comment: @Lil Yes, but are you sure its supposed to be $d^2/g$?  not just $d/g$?

Comment: @SimpleArt yeah it is $d^2$ so I substituted and got 1/4e$^2$/4f and then I substitute again?

Answer (score -1):

You have $4$ variables, $3$ equations, which, in theory, means it is impossible to find unique solutions for any of the variables.

Furthermore, [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=g%20%3D%204f,%202f%20%3D%203e,%202e%20%3D%204d,%20solve%20for%20d%5E2%2Fg) cannot solve the problem.

I'm not entirely sure if you are actually able to solve the problem.  Perhaps, the assumption that all unknowns are whole positive numbers may help.

Comment: I don't quite understand the first sentence, which is not true, I believe. But I like WolframAlpha, a lot --- it is certainly a good tool to try for simple algebraic questions.

Comment: @Jack You simply can't solve for $n$ unknowns using $k$ equations when $n>k$.

Comment: When you say "can't solve", I think you mean "the solution is not unique"?
 Consider for instance $x+y=1$. It is true that there are infinitely many solutions, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.